# JTable correct row number after filtering

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

Here is a try block which serves the purpose of filtering through table_job to find rows which match keyword. However, when the table model changes, I am struggling to obtain the correct row index. It always picks the the first row, even though the filtered result shows a row which is not first.

I understand you can do something with `fireTableDataChanged()`, but I am not sure HOW and WHERE to do this, in the `try` and `catch` block OR in the `setLabelText()` method which displays the content of the table as `. JLabel`

```
try 
{
    sql = "SELECT Job.jobID as 'Job ID', Employer.name as'Company', Job.title as 'Role', Job.description as  'Description', Job.type as 'Type', Job.benefits as 'Benefits', Job.closing as 'Closing Date' FROM Job INNER JOIN Employer ON Job.employerID=Employer.employerID ORDER BY Employer.name";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    TableModel model = DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs);
    table_job.setModel(model);
    final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    table_job.setRowSorter(sorter);               
    searchJob.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            String text = keyword.getText(); 
            if (text.length() == 0) 
            {
                sorter.setRowFilter(null);
            } 
            else 
            {
                sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
            }
        }             
    });
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();                
}

private void setLabelText() 
{
    try 
    {
        String table_click0 = (table_job.getModel().getValueAt(
                row, 0).toString());
        String sqlSt = "SELECT Employer.name, * FROM Job INNER JOIN Employer ON Job.employerID = Employer.employerID WHERE jobID='"+table_click0+"' ";
        //rest of code to Label text...
    }
```

The `String table_click0 = (table_job.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());` is picking up the wrong row, not the updated selected row. How can I take this into account?

Comment: 1) 1 line of white space in code is enough!  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (factor out the DB and hard-code some data).  3) This probably needs [`convertRowIndexToModel(int viewRowIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29).

Comment: I think you want to have a look at [JTable#convertRowIndexToModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int)). You may also want to have a read through [How to use Tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: @MadProgrammer @Andrew - thanks, what should I pass in as argument. because `table_job.convertRowIndexToModel();` alone  is illegal, should it be in `setLabelText()` or in the try catch block

Comment: Pass the index of the row from the view (JTable). If you want to convert the model index to the view, use JTable#convertRowIndexToView

Comment: @MuminAli: Instead of `table_job.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0)` use `table_job.getModel().getValueAt(table_job.convertRowIndexToModel(row), 0)`. If it does not help, post a complete example: an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet +1 with the `.toString()` at the end works

Comment: @GuillaumePolet you post that as an answer

Comment: @MuminAli Here you go, I posted this as an answer (although AndrewThompson gave it the right answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably need to convert your "row" value to a model index value (if your `row` value is retrieved from a "view" point of view), using `convertRowIndexToModel`. So just replace

```
String table_click0 = (table_job.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
```

with

```
String table_click0 = table_job.getModel().getValueAt(table_job.
                          convertRowIndexToModel(row), 0).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix: how to get the actual row in a filtered list

```
int row=getjTable().getSelectedRow();
if (getjTable().getRowSorter()!=null) {
    row = getjTable().getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(row);
}
```