# JTable search and deleting rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am learning how to use JTable and I have issues with both my search and delete function.

From my codes, if I checked row 1 and row 3 and press the delete button, it will remove perfectly.

If I enter J in my search textfield and press the search button, John and Jane will be displayed 
and now if I check the 2 rows and press the delete button then press the search button again,
John and Jane will be removed **including Kate and Ann**.

Please run the codes below if you guys still don't understand what I am saying. 
follow the steps that I mentioned and you will see what's wrong.
help me. Thanks

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class TableExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
    protected static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    private JTable table;
    TableModel model;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JButton button = new JButton("Delete");
    JTextField searchTextField = new JTextField(15);
    JButton searchBtn = new JButton("Search");
    JPanel flowLayoutPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;

    public TableExample() {
        String[] columnNames = {"Employer", "Company", "Salary", "Boolean"};
        Object[][] data = {
                {"Kate", "20",new Integer(5000), new Boolean(false)},
                {"John", "35", new Integer(3000), new Boolean(false)},
                {"Ann", "20", new Integer(4000), new Boolean(false)},
                {"Jane", "12", new Integer(4000), new Boolean(false)},
                {"May", "42", new Integer(4500), new Boolean(false)}
        };
        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {

                switch(column) {
                case 0: 
                case 1: return String.class;
                case 2: return Integer.class;
                case 3: return Boolean.class;
                default: return Object.class;

                }
            }
        };

        table = new JTable(model) {
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        table.setGridColor(Color.black);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for(int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); ++row) {
                    if((Boolean) table.getValueAt(row, 3) == true) {    
                        ((DefaultTableModel) model).removeRow(row);
                        row--;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        searchBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = searchTextField.getText();
                if (text.length() == 0) {
                    sorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
                }
            }
        });

        flowLayoutPanel.add(searchTextField);
        flowLayoutPanel.add(searchBtn);
        panel.add(flowLayoutPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(scrollPane , BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableExample  frame = new TableExample();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocation(150, 150);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the row number changes when you filter the table. Use *original row number* to delete a correct row.

Use [`table.convertRowIndexToModel(row)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29) to get the actual row number.

> Maps the index of the row in terms of the view to the underlying TableModel. If the contents of the model are not sorted the model and view indices are the same.

sample code:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for(int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); ++row) {
            if((Boolean) table.getValueAt(row, 3) == true) {    
                ((DefaultTableModel) model).removeRow(table.convertRowIndexToModel(row));
                row--;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302489/jtable-correct-row-number-after-filtering-in-java-solved)